# Stretched website using wordpress with elementor/divi

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, elementor, divi

is it possible to make website always stretched to screen like https://yukienatori-newyork.com/ , of course i dont need the water thing, i only need to be stretched (no scroll) with side menu.
is it possible to do this in wordpress using elementor or divi ?
Thank You ;)

Comment: Yes, it is possible

Answer (score 0):

In Divi, create a page with just one section of height 100vh. All your content will go in this section.

Make the row(s) inside the section 90% wide (with no max-width set) if you want their content to widen with the section.

Make sure (using the Theme Builder) that [your menu location is fixed](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/how-to-create-a-fixed-header-with-divis-position-options), so that it sits over the top of the page rather than pushing the page content down.

If you want a menu like the one used on your example website, you'll probably need to use a plugin.